# Multiple marker with address of specific one

Tags: javascript, wpf, google-maps-api-3, browser, google-maps-markers

how to show multiple markers with address of specific one among them?

I'm using google maps api 3 in WPF application

Comment: do you mean more markers with the same location?

Comment: No, with different locations (I'm getting locations from mobiles, so i dont know how locations do I have)
but I have i ListBox I want to visible the address for that the user clicks on it